# Why does $n \geq 2$ imply that $\frac n 2 < n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

It has been a while since I did math proof in school, and I just can't figure out why

> $$n \geq 2 \text{ implies that } \frac n 2 < n$$

Anything would help!  Thanks.

Comment: $n/2 < n$ iff $n<2n$ iff $0<n$

Comment: A formal proof requires you to use the order properties of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You probably want to use the ordered field axioms: "if $x \ge y$ then $x + z \ge y + z$",  and "if $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ then $xy \ge 0$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $n\geq 2$, it follows that $n>0$. Adding $n$ to both sides gives $2n>n$. Dividing both sides by $2$ then gives $n>\frac{n}{2}$. Intuitively, though, all you need to realize is that when you double any positive number, you get a number that is strictly larger than the original.

Answer (score 5):

Since $n>0$, $n<n+n=2n$. Diving both sides by $2$ gives you your answer.

Comment: This is also a good proof.  voted 1 up.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose not; then for $n\ge 2$, you have $n \ge 2n$.

Comment: which would imply that $1 \geq 2$, clearly not true, and hence proved by contradiction.

Comment: It boggles the mind why one would downvote a perfectly valid proof approach for an OP who openly says their proof skills have become rusty.